# Test for numbers in string in C

Tags: c, numbers

I want to make a function that tests for numbers in string values in C. I have no idea where to start so I did not provide any code. How can I do this?

Also, how can I make this work for hexadecimal?

Comment: You can start by explaining better what you want. Is the string only the number or the string can contain other charactere ? Is the number an integer ? Only in decimal representation ? In short, your "question" is too broad.

Comment: What "numbers are valid?  Sure _string_ `"123"` contains a number, but what about `"INF"`?

Comment: Also, `-1`, `+2`, and `4.77e23`... it gets to the point where you want to use a library function to convert the string to a number of the appropriate type

Answer (score 1):

`<ctype.h>` provides two functions, isalpha and isdigit, that may be what you're looking for. Just iterate on the characters of the string and check if `isdigit()` ever returns true.

Comment: well, what does isalpha do